# auxiliary index table corrupted?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Mysql err log is kept throwing errors like this:

```
2021-06-30T23:29:32.795948Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_1` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5161
2021-06-30T23:29:32.798119Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_2` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5162
2021-06-30T23:29:32.799672Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_3` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5163
2021-06-30T23:29:32.801289Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_4` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5164
2021-06-30T23:29:32.802702Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_5` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5165
2021-06-30T23:29:32.804163Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_6` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5166
2021-06-30T23:29:32.805517Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_BEING_DELETED` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5156
2021-06-30T23:29:32.807103Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_BEING_DELETED_CACHE` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5157
2021-06-30T23:29:32.808975Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_CONFIG` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5158
2021-06-30T23:29:32.810041Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_DELETED` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5159
2021-06-30T23:29:32.811121Z 3018 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `my_db`.`FTS_00000000000022f5_DELETED_CACHE` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 5160
```

The files are exist

```
# ll FTS*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql 13631488 Nov  9  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_1.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_2.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_3.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_4.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_5.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_00000000000030de_INDEX_6.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_BEING_DELETED_CACHE.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_BEING_DELETED.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Nov  9  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_CONFIG.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_DELETED_CACHE.ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql    98304 Oct 19  2018 FTS_00000000000022f5_DELETED.ibd
```

So I believe either the index or the tablespace is corrupted. How to fix it?

Comment: Did you move files around on disk?

Comment: Possibly. The db was not originally created/maintained by me and the developer has left the company. So nobody knows what he did. Can we recreate the index files? Or just simply drop the index from the tables?

Comment: Yes, for the second log:  `DROP` and `CREATE` that `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: Thanks. I could drop and recreate the index. However after recreated it, I could see it start throwing the error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem has been fixed after dropped all the relevant tables.

Firstly, look up the information schema to find out  the relevant information:

```
SELECT table_id, name, space from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE name LIKE 'f0Gno';
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS WHERE name LIKE 'DB_NAME/%';
```

Then, you will find out it's related to FULLINDEX:

```
select * from information_schema.statistics where table_schema='DB_NAME' and index_type='FULLTEXT';
```

Lastly, drop the index:

```
alter table DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME drop index '_keywords';
```

If you want to recreate the index:

```
create fulltext index _keywords on DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME(KEY1,KEY2...);
```

You can find the key name by desc the table.